# Generating a sequence of type T at compile time

Tags: c++, c++14, callable

I have the following problem:

```
template< typename callable, typename T , size_t... N_i>
void foo()
{
  using callable_out_type =  std::result_of_t< callable( /* T , ... , T <- sizeof...(N_i) many */ ) >;

  // ...
}
```

I want to get the result type of `callable` which takes `sizeof...(N_i)` many arguments of the type `T` as its input, e.g., `callable(1,2,3)` in case of `T==int` and `sizeof...(N_i)==3`. How can this be implemented?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe looking at [`std::integer_sequence`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence) will be helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not simply use:

```
using callable_out_type = std::result_of_t< callable( decltype(N_i, std::declval<T>())...) >;
```

you could also use a trick borrowed from [Columbo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40218447/generating-a-sequence-of-zeros-at-compile-time/40218498#40218498):

```
using callable_out_type =  std::result_of_t< callable(std::tuple_element_t<(N_i, 0), std::tuple<T>>...) >;
```

or even:

```
using callable_out_type =  std::result_of_t< callable(std::enable_if_t<(N_i, true), T>...) >;
```

Answer (score 12):

We can use a type alias to hook onto the expansion of `N_i`, but always give back `T`.

```
template <class T, std::size_t>
using eat_int = T;

template< typename callable, typename T , size_t... N_i>
void foo()
{
  using callable_out_type = std::result_of_t< callable(eat_int<T, N_i>...) >;

  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You could write the following helpers

```
template<typename T, size_t>
using type_t = T;

template<typename Callable, typename T, size_t... Is>
auto get_result_of(std::index_sequence<Is...>) -> std::result_of_t<Callable(type_t<T,Is>...)>;

template<typename Callable, typename T, size_t N>
using result_of_n_elements = decltype(get_result_of<Callable, T>(std::make_index_sequence<N>{}));
```

then in your `foo` you'd write

```
template< typename callable, typename T , size_t N>
void foo()
{
    using callable_out_type = result_of_n_elements<callable, T, N>;
}
```

[live demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/1RczxAYwcuPQBv7x)