# Generate a sequence of null values follwed by one at compiletime

Tags: c++, parameter-pack

I have a problem similar to

[Generating a sequence of zeros at compile time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40218447/generating-a-sequence-of-zeros-at-compile-time)

However, in my case I have no pack to expand. The situation is like this:

```cpp
template<size_t N>
void foo()
{ bar(T{}, ..., static_cast<T>(1)); }
```

There are `N - 1` T{}:s followed by a one.

It may happen that `T` is not usable as a non-type template parameter. There are two differences compared to the linked post

1. In the linked post, there is already a parameter pack to rely on
2. In the linked post, it is assumed that all arguments are integers

I may use a solution that require C++20

Comment: The "problem" you present to us and ask for help with is a *solution* to an (for us) unknown problem. What is that original and underlying problem you need to solve? Why do you think the proposed solution would solve it? Why don't you ask about the underlying problem directly instead, and present your solution as a possible way to solve it? It will help us write better and more context-aware answers, and maybe even come up with other possible solutions to your problem. In sort: This is very much an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: `T{}` is not null value

Comment: @appleapple There is no generic "null" value in C++, but T{} is a good approximation. Arithmetic types set to zero (neutral under addition), pointers set to nullptr (the "origin" in address space), etc. It would be nice to have a generalized null concept similar to std::hash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you generate the sequence yourself

```
#include <utility>
template<std::size_t N>
void foo(){
    [&]<std::size_t...I>(std::index_sequence<I...>){  
        bar((I,T{}) ... , static_cast<T>(1)); 
    }(std::make_index_sequence<N-1>());
}
```

Comment: Nice trick. So use a type that makes the pack deducible.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn `N` into `std::index_sequence<0, .., N-1>` with [`std::make_index_sequence`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence), then you might expand your pack as you want:

```
template<size_t N>
void foo()
{
    []<std::size_t...Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>){
        bar(T{(static_cast<void>(Is), 0)}..., static_cast<T>(1));
    } (std::make_index_sequence<N - 1>());
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/jnrWs1vTb)

template lambda is C++20, if you cannot use it, you have to make a similar template helper function.